# May a wife go a place against her husband’s will

Tags: halacha, marriage, kavod, shalom-bayit, even-haezer

According to Halacha, if a husband tells his wife she can’t go somewhere (for example, the supermarket) is the wife obligated to listen to her husband? Or can she (at least by halacha) go against her husband’s wishes so long as she doesn’t seclude with any man?

Comment: [אבל גנאי הוא לאשה שתהיה יוצאה תמיד פעם בחוץ פעם ברחובות. ויש לבעל למנע אשתו מזה ולא יניחנה לצאת אלא כמו פעם אחת בחדש או כמו פעמים בחדש לפי הצרך.](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Marriage.13.11)

Comment: @shmosel ,you forgot the line above that "שֶׁאֵינָהּ בְּבֵית הַסֹּהַר עַד שֶׁלֹּא תֵּצֵא וְלֹא תָּבוֹא" ,this is obviously a minhag hamkom(daas yehudis) type din. Just like no one in America is wearing a Redid.

Comment: The question in reverse would be just as valid - for *shalom bayit* reasons.